# How can I get the name of the class defined in the template section of my first class?

Tags: java, android, class, templates

I've seen codes like the following that define the template type as some other class:

```
MyAndroidClass<MyAnotherAndroidClass> myAndroidClassInstanceVar;
```

Now, I can get the class name of the MyAndroidClass via the MyAndroidClass.class.getSimpleName() method.

But now I want to get the class name of "MyAnotherAndroidClass" defined in the template type of this class. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can store the `Class<T>` as an attribute of `MyAndroidClass<T>`. If you show us your class, it would be benefitial.

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure, you won't be able to necessarily. You can, however, accept a parameter that is the generic type, and grab the `Class` via `getClass`.

For example(null will NPE):

```
class Test<E>{
    Class getclazz(E e){
        return e.getClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless the actual value passed is `null`.

Comment: @hexafraction : can you show me an example of what you mean by "accept a parameter that is the generic type, and grab the Class via getClass" ?

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 That is the example. Accept a parameter of `E` in some method or the constructor, and get the class of that.